# Lucene TermQuery and BooleanQuery case sensitivity

Tags: java, text, lucene, text-analysis

I am relatively new to Lucene and trying out a few examples on my own. One thing I have come to notice is that the `TermQuery` seems to look for an exact match (case-sensitive), whereas if I construct a `BooleanQuery` with the same `TermQuery`, it does a case-insensitive search. More specifically, if I just search with:

```
new TermQuery(new Term("content", "sample_word"));
```

It doesn't consider a document with `Sample_word` (with the uppercase S) as a match. However if I search with the following:

```
Query booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
booleanQuery.add(new TermQuery(new Term("content", "sample_word")), Occur.MUST);
```

It does consider it a match. Why is it so?

My guess is that with a `TermQuery`, there is no default analyzer that kicks in, but with a `BooleanQuery` there is? Is there any way some analyzer could be forced to work with `TermQuery` as well?

Comment: Nope, no analyzer will be applied to the query in either case. The two queries you've shown are functionally identical.

Comment: @femtoRgon Thanks. Looks like I was mistaken in my findings. In my documents, the lowercase conversion was done during indexing phase. That's why the TermQuery was unable to find the document with the uppercase word. Same with the BooleanQuery.